# Find out whether a method is protected or public

Tags: php, protected, public-method

With this code I'm trying to test if I can call certain functions

```
if (method_exists($this, $method))
    $this->$method();
```

however now I want to be able to restrict the execution if the $method is protected, what would I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php).

```
class Foo { 
    public function bar() { } 
    protected function baz() { } 
    private function qux() { } 
}
$f = new Foo();
$f_reflect = new ReflectionObject($f);
foreach($f_reflect->getMethods() as $method) {
    echo $method->name, ": ";
    if($method->isPublic()) echo "Public\n";
    if($method->isProtected()) echo "Protected\n";
    if($method->isPrivate()) echo "Private\n";
}
```

Output:

```
bar: Public
baz: Protected
qux: Private
```

You can also instantiate the ReflectionMethod object by class and function name:

```
$bar_reflect = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
echo $bar_reflect->isPublic(); // 1
```

Comment: Do I need to test whether the $method exists, or would is public be 0 if the method is undefined?

Comment: if you try to construct ReflectionMethod on a method that doesn't exist it will throw an exception.  the first thing he did with `ReflectionObject` iterates thru existing methods, so thats not an issue

Comment: @Moak: You can use [`ReflectionObject::hasMethod`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php) to test for method existence.  This works *even for private methods* when checking outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReflectionMethod.  You can use `isProtected` and `isPublic` as well as `getModifiers`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getmodifiers.php

```
$rm = new ReflectionMethod($this, $method); //first argument can be string name of class or an instance of it.  i had get_class here before but its unnecessary
$isPublic = $rm->isPublic();
$isProtected = $rm->isProtected();
$modifierInt = $rm->getModifiers();
$isPublic2 = $modifierInt & 256; $isProtected2 = $modifierInt & 512;
```

As for checking whether or not the method exists, you can do it as you do now with `method_exists` or just attempt to construct the ReflectionMethod and an exception will be thrown if it doesn't exist.  `ReflectionClass` has a function `getMethods` to get you an array of all of a class's methods if you'd like to use that.

Disclaimer - I don't know PHP Reflection too well, and there might be a more direct way to do this with ReflectionClass or something else